# post json as httpcontent to webapi

Tags: android, json, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

I have a webapi that i want to post json to and then return json. Im using xamarin to create my android app but it doesn't seem to support PostAsJsonAsync method for the httpclient. So im now trying PostAsync method that post httpcontent. So what i want to do is convert my json to so that it is of format httpcontent and json so that i can post it to my webapi. This is my code:

```
        var clientRequest = new ResourceByNameRequest
        {
            Name = "G60",
            UserId = "1"
        };

     var param = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clientRequest);
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(param, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var client = new HttpClient();
            var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
            var result = client.PostAsync("https://mctwebapi-test.entrematic.com/api/Resource/ResourceByName?", content, cancellationToken).Result;
            return reslist;
```

this just runs till the timeout. I can't figure out why it doesn't work. If you have any other suggestions on how to post json to webapi using Xamarin im more than happy to try that out!
Plz help!

Comment: Have you tested the address is reachable from the Android client?

Comment: not sure what you that means. Plz tell me more!:)

Comment: Can you open https://mctwebapi-test.entrematic.com/ from the device browser?

Comment: yes i can. Or if i put https:// infront atleast

Comment: "A quite ordinary G60" response takes about 24s using PostMan (Chrome) and ~37s on Android device (S3). Default HttpClient timeout is 40s I believe so try to set the timeout higher. I am using this wrapper around HttpClient and JSON serializer(s): https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Plugins/Web/Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Services.Web.RestClient/RestCoreClient.cs